# After saving to txt file all of the data is corrupted

Tags: c++, file, binary, txt

I was trying to write a primitive code that

- would compress a text file by changing every character into a series of bits (length depends on the number of characters)
- and after all of this is done the script would take all of these bits put them into one string add more bits if necessary(to make the size of binary string multiple of 8)
- and then change groups of 8 bits to their ASCII value

and everything seems to be working ok but and the end when I try to save the compressed string,
I check to see how it looks and it's just a bunch of random characters.
I don't know what went wrong

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<char> lista;
    map<char,string> znaki;
    string szyfr;
    char ch;
    fstream file;
    file.open( "test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out );
    while(file >> ch)
    {
        if(find(lista.begin(), lista.end(), ch) == lista.end())
        {
            lista.push_back(ch);
        }
    }
    sort(lista.begin(), lista.end());
    int lista_rozm=lista.size();

    string dekod;
    dekod+=bitset<8>(lista_rozm).to_string();
    int length = ceil(log2(lista.size()));

    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
        dekod+=lista[i];
        string binaryString = bitset<8>(i).to_string();
        if (binaryString.size() > length)
            binaryString = binaryString.substr(binaryString.size() - length);
        else if (binaryString.size() < length)
            binaryString = std::string(length - binaryString.size(), '0') + binaryString;
        znaki.insert(pair<char,string>(lista[i],binaryString));
    }
    file.close();

    file.open( "test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out );
    char ch2;
    while(file >> ch2){
        szyfr+=znaki[ch2];
    }
    while((szyfr.size() % 8)!=0){

        szyfr+='1';
    }
    stringstream sstream(szyfr);
    string output;
    while(sstream.good()){
        bitset<8> bits;
        sstream >> bits;
        output += char(bits.to_ulong());
        cout<<output<<endl;
    }

    dekod+=output;
    //cout<<dekod;
    file.close();
    fstream file2;
    file2.open("wynik.txt", ios::out );
    file2<<output;
    file2<<dekod;
    //cout<<dekod;
    file2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Like i said i tried to make a code that would compress a txt file but i failed

Comment: Note that sorting a message removes the context that comes from the initial ordering. This is hard to recover, and typically the metadata needed to recover the order exceeds whatever savings you got from sorting.

Comment: This doesn't look "minimal" to me. See [mcve]

Comment: Start by isolating the problem. Encode a small message where you know exactly what the output file should look like because you computed the result by hand. If you don't get the expected output, ignore the decoder for now and focus on making the encoder do exactly what you need it to do. When you know you have the encoder working, step through the decoder with a debugger looking for where it deviates from your expectations.

Comment: What do you expect the compressed data to look like, if not "a bunch of random characters"? Please post an example input, the output you expect, and the actual output.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).